# i m new to sharepoint and confuse, where coding take place in sharepoint application as other normar asp.net application

Tags: sharepoint

i m new to sharepoint and bit confuse,

i don't understand where coding take place in sharepoint as other asp.net application.

how it work if i have to create a page for adding record to database.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about [SharePoint features](http://miguelmoreno.net/sandbox/sharepointeventhandler/).

You may be interested in [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) so you don't have to write those XML manifest and feature files.